# Python - Finding the number of squares by connected coordinates

Tags: python

If I have a list of lists as below ,

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 5], [2, 6], [4, 8], [5, 6], [6, 7],
 [7, 8], [6, 10], [7, 11], [8, 12], [10, 11],
 [10, 14], [12, 16], [14, 15], [15, 16]]
```

And another list as below :

```
([[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [1, 5], [4, 8],
     [6, 7], [5, 9], [6, 10], [7, 11], [8, 12],
     [9, 13], [10, 11], [12, 16], [13, 14], [14, 15], [15, 16]]
```

The above 2 lists can be visualized as in the image, where each point is represented by a list . 
 [image]

I want to write a program in python which detects the number of squares formed by the connecting points .

I know there is a graph traversal where every visited node can be tracked as we traverse through the graph . But in this case , there is no direction mentioned .

I am not asking for a complete solution here nor is the case that i have not researched enough . Any advice on how to approach this problem would really help as i am just not able to get a start to this .

THanks in advance .

Comment: stackoverflow is about programming, not finding the correct algorithm. You should probably ask your question in [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: "The above 2 lists can be visualized as in the image, where each point is represented by a list" --- I think it would be more accurate to say your lists represent "edges" in the graph. However, your node names (1, 2, 3, ...) have nothing to do with a shape, so I'd change their names from being linearly indexed to being pairwise indexed like a matrix, which should make it easier to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the length of side, in this case it is 3, the squares inside is limited and can be described as list of sides just like your input.

In your case, there are 9 (1*1) squares, 4 (2*2) squares, and 1 (3*3) squares inside.
The first (1*1) square can be described as `{(1,2), (1,5), (2,6), (5,6)}`.
I use tuple instead of list here, because tuple can be element of set in python, while list can not. If we transform the input like this, we get the graph as

```
{(1, 2), (3, 4), (1, 5), (2, 6), (4, 8), (5, 6), (6, 7),
 (7, 8), (6, 10), (7, 11), (8, 12), (10, 11),
 (10, 14), (12, 16), (14, 15), (15, 16)}
```

The first square `{(1,2), (1,5), (2,6), (5,6)}` is subset of the graph set (we can use the python function `issubset` to check), then we can say it is in the graph. Use the same way to check whether all the 14 squares are in the graph, you get the number.

If the side length is big, like 100, you can use a loop to get all possible squares inside.

```
for point in all_points:
    for side_length in range(1, N):
        if the_square_is_valid:
            gen_the_side_set
```

---

As tiboas_k commented, the algorithm complexity is high.
I just came up with a new solution.

First transform the input to

```
{(1, 2), (3, 4), (1, 5), (2, 6), (4, 8), (5, 6), (6, 7),
 (7, 8), (6, 10), (7, 11), (8, 12), (10, 11),
 (10, 14), (12, 16), (14, 15), (15, 16)}
```

as above. Then get all possible top left nodes, it is the set of first element of the side pair.

```
 {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 14, 15}
```

for every possible top left nodes, check whether square of length 1, 2 ... n with this node as top left node exists in the input graph. It can be optimized, for length k, if the top side or left side is missing, then you don't need to check k+1 to n.

In this algorithm, we don't need to generate all possible squares, just check all possible squares in the input graph, and as soon as we find one side missing, we can return false, don't have to check all sides. It should be faster.

Comment: "If the side length is big, like 100" Good luck with that, this algorithm seems to be O(n³) (n being the side length of the point matrix). Not saying that there necessarily is a better one (although there probably is, at least a bit better), just wanted to point out.

Comment: @huwenchao -  The input will have integers only in the range of 1 through 16 .  If i consider your opinion , which is having all possible combinations pre-stored and then checking if any smaller graph is a subset of the bigger one , wont i have to store all combinations so that the smaller ones can be checked against them ?

Comment: @user1411837 You don't have to "pre-store" all possible squares, you can easily write a helper function for creating the set of edges for a square with side length k starting at point (x,y). (And for side length 16, this would indeed be a viable solution.)

Comment: Actually, it's even more like O(n^4), as you have to check squares of sizes 1..n for all nxn positions, and each square will contain on the order of n points that have to be checked. Still, for n=16 not a problem.

Comment: @user1411837 as tobias_k said，you don't have to store them, but if you find it hard to write the helper function, pre-store them also works, and it is easier to implement if you have integers only in the range of 1 through 16 .

Comment: @tobias_k I agree with you, this algorithm is straightforward but not good for big graph. I just came up with a new solution, I will post it later.

Comment: @huwenchao - Though i've accepted your logic , i am still not sure how do i use that logic to count the number of squares . Could you help me figure that out ?

Comment: "for every possible top left nodes, check whether square of length 1, 2 ... n with this node as top left node exists in the input graph." The point is how to determine that a square exists or not .

Comment: @user1411837 You can define a helper function `gen_square_sides_set(top_left_node, square_length)`，which generates the side sets of the given top_left_node and square_length. For example, if you have 6 as top left node, and square_length 2, then the side sets is `{(6,7), (7,8), (8,12), (12,16), (6,10), (10,14), (14,15), (15,16)}`, you can check whether this set is subset of your input graph, then you know whether this square is in input graph.

Comment: @user1411837 The logic is similar to list all combination of inside squares, the key difference is you don't need to list all combination and check if they are subset of the input graph one by one, you start from the possible top left nodes in the input graph, check whether squares with side length 1, 2 ... n is in the input graph. We can work less to get the result.

Comment: @huwenchao - Correct , i understood your logic . But where i am stuck is in generating the logic behind the sides . For instance , the example that you have given with top_left_node as 6 and square length of 2,what is the logic behind generating those side sets ? I can't think of any . For eg : (6,7) , (7,8) can be found be incrementing each value by 1 . How about (6,10) ? There is no way to tell that 10 is a possible side with left node as 6 . Is that correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172139/discussion-between-user1411837-and-huwenchao).